How do lawyers find the contact information for lawyers representing a company?
If a lawyer needs to contact the legal representative of a company, how do they get this contact information?  Is there a formal way (directory)?  And/or informal way(s) (well-followed convention for email addresses like lawyer@company.com)?

Google is pretty standard.

united-states
In litigation, lawyers disclose their contact information when they first become involved in a case on behalf of a client in a filing with the court that is available as a matter of public record.
Outside of litigation, lawyers often don't know who the company's lawyers are, or if the company even has lawyers, unless they have dealt with that company before. But, every company has an official known as a registered agent, who is the official contact person for the company to whom legal process or letters can be sent. The list of registered agents in the U.S. is generally maintained by the Secretary of State for the state government where the business have been formed and in other states where it is authorized to do business.
Alternately, the lawyer can call a non-lawyer representative of the company whose contact information is listed the same way you would locate anyone else, and ask.

canada
Generally, one has no need to contact a legal representative of a corporation, and the corporation need not make their legal counsel available for contact. There is nothing special about legal counsel that makes them more available to be contacted by people outside of the corporation.
Corporations also need only provide an address for service of legal documents.
But, options are:

ask the corporation for contact info of legal counsel;
begin legal action against the corporation, in which case, they will almost certainly direct further communication to be with their legal counsel assigned to the matter, and the counsel contact information will be part of the responding pleadings.


australia
Legally communicating with a company is pretty straightforward if a little old fashioned.
All companies are required by law to have a registered office and that information is available from the regulator, the Australian Securities and Investment Commission (ASIC). It may be an ordinary place of business for the company, but some companies use their external accountant’s address. Anything posted or delivered to that address is deemed to have been received by the company, even if the company is no longer there — the company is obliged to keep the information up to date.
In addition s109X of the Corporations Act allows personal service on a director located in Australia (there must always be one). It also provides for service on an administrator or liquidator if applicable.
